# Where would round robin scheduling be used?

Tags: scheduler

Can't seem to find any example for where Round robin CPU scheduling would be used in a real life **computer** example. Where would it most commonly be found?

Comment: "ok, kids, get off the swingset so that other group of kids can get on".

Comment: great example! Maybe I should have reworded that in terms of computers

Comment: Just where did you search for examples? Did you try [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin)? That would be a fairly obvious place to start online research.

Comment: You can even upvote answers if you are satisfied with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Round robin is a nice scheduling for processes with the same priority or in an OS without priorities or priorities based only on groups (Minix 2).
It is also ok, when you use a few independent programs, because process starvation is not likely to happen.

Answer (score 2):

Tasks with the same priority are scheduled practically with round-robin.